# Switch in bottomsheet not changing status on Flutter

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I have some problem using a switch inside a bottomsheet.
When I tap on it, it doesn't change it's status. Only for the first time, the state changes correctly.

This is the simple code I'm using:

```
  bool _switchValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('SHOW BOTTOM SHEET'),
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                child: CupertinoSwitch(
                  value: _switchValue,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _switchValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                )
              );
            });
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to put the switch in its own `StatefulWidget` and use a callback to return the value to your main class. A bottom sheet uses a different context so calling `setState` in your example above doesn't work.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _switchValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('SHOW BOTTOM SHEET'),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return BottomSheetSwitch(
                    switchValue: _switchValue,
                    valueChanged: (value) {
                      _switchValue = value;
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomSheetSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomSheetSwitch({@required this.switchValue, @required this.valueChanged});

  final bool switchValue;
  final ValueChanged valueChanged;

  @override
  _BottomSheetSwitch createState() => _BottomSheetSwitch();
}

class _BottomSheetSwitch extends State<BottomSheetSwitch> {
  bool _switchValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _switchValue = widget.switchValue;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: CupertinoSwitch(
          value: _switchValue,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              _switchValue = value;
              widget.valueChanged(value);
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. However, I don't quite understand the exact mechanism for updating the state here. Why do we need a valueChanged callback and how does it actually work. We have not called setState() method in the MyHomePage class, still the callback function manages to change the state.

Answer (score 17):

Use **StatefulBuilder** to change status of switch inside BottomSheet

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
     context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {  
      return Container(  
       child: StatefulBuilder(  
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter stateSetter) {  
         return CupertinoSwitch(  
           value: _switchValue,  
           onChanged: (val) {  
             stateSetter(() => _switchValue = val); 
           },);  
         },  
       ),  
      )  
   });
```

Comment: If this solution not working then try doing ```flutter clean```
This will clear the caches

Comment: @Rishabh why we need to use StatefulBuilder and why normal setState does not work inside BottomSheet?

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution!  I needed to see a simple usage of the ```StateSetter``` to understand it.